# Installing cocoapods on macOS Mojave

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I have looked through  a lot of these questions and none seem to apply. I am trying to install cocoapods and run pod init in my xcode project. When I run `sudo gem install cocoa pods`I get right the end and see this:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20200314-453-8td9mi.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
```

And of course when I run pod init inside my Xcode project I get:

```
-bash: pod: command not found
```

Comment: This was also opened as an [Issue on CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9568) on GitHub.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like CocoaPods 1.9.0, the latest version as of this writing, depends on a newer version of Ruby than 2.3.7. But macOS Mojave only includes Ruby 2.3.7, so you have a few different options.

- Upgrade to macOS Catalina and get Ruby 2.6.3
- Use Ruby Version Manager to install a newer version of Ruby
- Install an older version of CocoaPods
  `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4`

#### Sources

Other people have trouble with CocoaPods 1.9.0 on Mojave. [1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9568) [2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9568#issuecomment-592158920) [3](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9568#issuecomment-599143219) [4](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9602) [5](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9538#issue-565341505)

Some people got it working by upgrading to Ruby 2.6 or newer. [1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9538#issuecomment-586581623) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60620170)

Comment: This is now a known issue https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9641

Comment: cocoapods 1.9.1 installed OK for me on Mojave with ruby 2.3.6 using `sudo gem install cocoapods` (not specifying version)

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue with this

https://medium.com/@pfxstudio21/cocoapods-error-error-installing-cocoapods-396ef7a1393d

It will work for you, it did the trick for me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/295232) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.