# Installing cocoapods to macOS Catalina

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

In my mac mini I've running Catalina 10.15.7. I've also installed Xcode 12.4. Now as I'm using third party library I'm trying to install cocoapods in my mac.
So I used this -

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

which I got from [official](https://cocoapods.org/) website.

But I'm getting this -

```
Password:
Fetching concurrent-ruby-1.1.8.gem
Fetching fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gem
Fetching i18n-1.8.10.gem
Fetching thread_safe-0.3.6.gem
Fetching tzinfo-1.2.9.gem
Fetching activesupport-5.2.5.gem
Fetching nap-1.1.0.gem
Fetching httpclient-2.8.3.gem
Fetching algoliasearch-1.27.5.gem
Fetching ffi-1.15.0.gem
Fetching ethon-0.12.0.gem
Fetching typhoeus-1.4.0.gem
Fetching netrc-0.11.0.gem
Fetching public_suffix-4.0.6.gem
Fetching addressable-2.7.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-core-1.10.1.gem
Fetching claide-1.0.3.gem
Fetching cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.4.gem
Fetching cocoapods-downloader-1.4.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-search-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-trunk-1.5.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gem
Fetching molinillo-0.6.6.gem
Fetching atomos-0.1.3.gem
Fetching colored2-3.1.2.gem
Fetching nanaimo-0.3.0.gem
Fetching xcodeproj-1.19.0.gem
Fetching escape-0.0.4.gem
Fetching fourflusher-2.3.1.gem
Fetching gh_inspector-1.1.3.gem
Fetching ruby-macho-1.4.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-1.10.1.gem
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.8
Successfully installed i18n-1.8.10
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.9
Successfully installed activesupport-5.2.5
Successfully installed nap-1.1.0
Successfully installed fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Successfully installed httpclient-2.8.3
A new major version is available for Algolia! Please now use the https://rubygems.org/gems/algolia gem to get the latest features.
Successfully installed algoliasearch-1.27.5
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods: 
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/ext/ffi_c/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210406-1384-1vtmk4p.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:10:in `system_libffi_usable?'
from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/gem_make.out
```

I've seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384382/installing-cocoapods-on-macos-mojave?newreg=7300f4ae27a84bc6b2f8ddb052b1db4b) but my ruby version is -

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
```

I've also take [a look in this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1727) but could not able to solve the problem.

**Edit:** 
I've used this -

```
xcode-select --install
```

but got -
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

So, Is there any ruby dependency I've to install first or I just missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and trying different things I've solved my problem -

I've used -

```
brew cleanup -d -v 
brew install cocoapods
```

Now I've installed cocoapod on my machine.

**Edit:**

I'm facing problem when I entered -

```
pod init
```

It gives me an error -

```
[!] Unable to locate the CocoaPods.app application bundle. 
Please ensure the application is available and launch it at least once.
Illegal instruction: 4
```

To solve this I've used -

```
pod setup
```

And Voilà!! It works!!

Answer (score 0):

Run: `cd $(xcode-select -p)/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0`

Then run: `sudo ln -sf universal-darwin20 universal-darwin19`

Then finally install cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`